# Z-index кнопка закрыть на меню

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index

Работаю над сайтом, и мне нужно сделать меню, которое будет появлятся из кнопки (кнопка после нажатия меняет картинку, но я думаю это не так важно). Так вот, проблема в том, что меню, реализовано через модальное окно, выравненное по правому верхнему углу. А когда оно появляется, то собой перекрывает кнопку открытия и закрытия этого самого меню. Модальное окно - это просто "display: none" тег . Пробовал через z-index, но почему-то не работает. Подскажите как можно реализовать перекрытие кнопкой меню модального окна.
Вот код.

```
/* HTML окна */
<div id="modal-fillip" class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-1 offset-11">
                    <img id="modal-fillip-close" src="images/close.png" onclick="modal_fillip_close()">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <img id="fillip" src="images/fillip.png">
                </div>
             <div class="col-8">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
/* HTML Меню */
<div class="col-1">
   <p class="text-right">
      <img id="menu" src="images/menu.png" onclick="menu()">
   </p>
</div>
```

```
/* JavaScript */
function menu(params) {
    if (counter == 0){
        var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
        var head = document.getElementById("header");
        var modal = document.getElementById("modal-menu")
        modal.style.display = "block";
        menu.style.zIndex = "999";
        modal.style.zIndex = "1";
        menu.src = "images/close.png";
        head.style.transitionProperty = "filter";
        head.style.transitionDuration = "250ms";
        head.style.filter = "brightness(40%)";
        counter++;
        document.onmousewheel=document.onwheel=function(){ 
            return false;
        };
    }else{
        var head = document.getElementById("header");
        var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
        var modal = document.getElementById("modal-menu")
        modal.style.display = "none";
        menu.style.zIndex = "999";
        menu.src = "images/menu.png";
        head.style.transitionProperty = "filter";
        head.style.transitionDuration = "250ms";
        head.style.filter = "brightness(100%)";
        counter--;
        document.onmousewheel=document.onwheel=function(){ 
            return true;
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: а как у вас меню и модальное окно относительно друг друга расположены? `z-index` хитрая вещь, некоторые вещи с помощью него принципиально не сделать - например, дочерний элемент объекта A не может быть выше объекта B, при том что сам объект А ниже объекта B. А вы не думали (если вам нужна кнопка) просто продублировать ее в модальном окне и все

Comment: Оба находятся в правом верхнем углу, не считая margin

Comment: сам код у вас очень перегружен - зачем такие сложности? все надо/можно сделать через css, а при нажатии меню надо просто менять класс один на другой

Comment: Ай, да ладно, тык-тык, и в продакшен, а как пофиксить проблему??

Comment: Ну ладно - тогда `z-index` работает только тогда, когда установлено свойство `position`, например `position: relative`. Установите его для начала для родителя кнопки и модального окна и для самих кнопки и модального окна - на позиционирование это не влияет, а z-index должен заработать... вроде

Comment: Добавил ```position``` к блокам родителям, к меню и к блоку модального окна, даже каждому приписал z-index, но ничего не поменялось(

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113433/discussion-between-zhihar-and-kurpenok).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index` работает только для элементов с одинаковым родителем, а в данном случае кнопка имеет родителем `<header>`, а модальное окно - нет, поэтому не получится перекрыть модальное окно лишь одним элементом `<header>`, а не всем хедером.

варианты выхода:

1. занести модальное окно в header
2. вынести кнопки меню из header
3. продублировать кнопку из header в модальном окне (но это не очень вариант - плодит сущности лишние)